# Appending and Inserting with Dask Arrays giving mismatch between chunks and shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I have a Dask array with shape `(1001,256,1,256)` (data over 1001 timesteps with len(x)=len(z)=256 and len(y)=1).

I need to pad the x-dimension with arrays of shape `(1001,2,1,256)`, which I'm attempting with `dask.array.insert()` and `dask.array.append()`, which are equivalent to numpy functions of the same names.

This should result in an array with shape `(1001,260,1,256)`.

My arrays look like this:

```
print(prepend_array)
print(append_array)
print(data)
```

> ```
> dask.array<getitem, shape=(1001, 2, 1, 256), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1001, 2, 1, 256),chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
> dask.array<getitem, shape=(1001, 2, 1, 256), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1001, 2, 1, 256),chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
> dask.array<getitem, shape=(1001, 256, 1, 256), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1001, 8, 1, 256),chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
> ```

I then do (with insert and append together - the error comes from insert):

```
padded_data = da.append(
        da.insert(
            data,
            0,
            prepend_padding,
            axis=1),
        append_padding,
        axis=1)
```

But see the following error (from dask.array.rechunk):

> ```
> ValueError: Chunks and shape must be of the same length/dimension. Got chunks=((1001,), (1,), (1,), (256,)), shape=(1001, 1, 2, 1, 256)
> ```

It seems I'm gaining a dimension, where I'm expecting to add to an existing dimension. The obvious answer to me is `axis=1` is the issue, but I've been unable to resolve it, as any valid value (0,1,2,3) gives a `len(shape)=5`, not the expected `4`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I jumped on here too soon, but rather than remove my question I'll provide the answer.

The mistake was not in `axis=1`, but in `0`, or rather, `obj=0` in `dask.array.insert(arr, obj, values, axis)`

Solution:

```
padded_data = da.append(
        da.insert(
            data,
            [0,0,0,0],
            prepend_padding,
            axis=1),
        append_padding,
        axis=1)
```

`[0,0,0,0]` is the position in `data` before which `prepend_padding` is inserted - [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.insert.html#dask.array.insert).